# Unix/bash :Print filename as first string before each line in a log file

Tags: bash, file, unix, text

Looking for help on how to get append the name of the file as 1st string in each row of the file.

A file which has only content. I am trying to merge 2 files but with the content should have first string as the name of the file then row 1. etc. Lets consider  2 files with name FileA and FileB. FileA has 2 lines, FileB has 2 lines.

FileA

```
Tom is Cat
Jerry is Mouse
```

FileB

```
Cat is Tom
Mouse is Jerry
```

Expected Output of merged file

```
FileA Tom is Cat
FileA Jerry is Mouse
FileB Cat is Tom
FileB Mouse is Jerry.
```

I am struggling to find a solution to this. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed` to substitute the filename at the beginning of each line of the file:

```
sed 's/^/FileA /' fileA >> mergedFile
sed 's/^/FileB /' fileB >> mergedFile
```

For an arbitrary number of files you can loop over all the filenames, and construct the `sed` substitution command dynamically using the variable with the filenames.

```
while read -r f
do
    sed "s|^|$f |" "$f"
done < file.txt > merge.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will try this method today.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you elaborate more on how to use loop here with n number of filenames. I was using xargs < file.txt cat > merge.txt.  But due to the name of the file addition, this solution will not work. Can you give a small example of how it can use loop over filenames with sed within it.

Comment: I added that to the answer.

Comment: let me try this.

Comment: giving this error "sed -e expression #1 , char 6 : unknown option to s. "

Comment: Does `file.txt` contain filenames or pathnames? If it contains `/` characters, you need to use a different delimiter in the `s` command.

Comment: It had file path till the name of the file.This is definitely good to know. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` and brace expansion.

```
awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' file{A,B} | tee mergefile
```

file names can be anything if that is not what you have, just put them as argument with `awk`

```
awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' filefoo filebar filemore ...
```

Can be done with `grep` also if your `grep` has the `-H` option/flag

```
grep -H . fileA fileB
```

Again filenames can be anything.

Using `tee` to send the output to `stdout` and mergefile.

Comment: Thankyou for sharing your idea. I am checking these steps now.

Comment: I was trying to see what does grep -H does but coudnt find a valuable reference. Feel free to throw some light on this.

Comment: On, GNU grep, `grep --help | grep -- -H`

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer `ripgrep` over `grep` these two commands produce the same output:

```
$ grep --with-filename '' File*
$ rg --with-filename --no-heading --no-line-number '' File*
FileA:Tom is Cat
FileA:Jerry is Mouse
FileB:Cat is Tom
FileB:Mouse is Jerry
```

Comment: Thankyou. I will try this method today.

Comment: I am confused here. I am using a usual find command to find the impacted files. Now with the list of impacted files i have to create a final file whose 1st line of each row should be the filename (its source). In this context, can you tell how i can use ripgrep. Havent used it before and i am reading about it now.

Comment: If you were using find you could do something like this: `$ find . -name 'File*' -exec rg --with-filename --no-heading --no-line-number '' {} \;` or `$ find . -name 'File*' -exec grep --with-filename '' {} \;`. Ripgrep is just a grep replacement that is fast and has some nice features.

Comment: This is interesting. I can definitely refer to this for tuning. Thankyou.